# Extract a certain part of a string after a key phrase using pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, extract

I have an NFL dataset with a 'description' column with details about the play. Each successful pass and run play has a string that's structured like:

"(12:25) (No Huddle Shotgun) P.Manning pass short left to W.Welker pushed ob at DEN 34 for 10 yards (C.Graham)."

How do I locate/extract the number after "for" in the string, and place it in a new column?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Series [str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) string method:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([["(12:25) (No Huddle Shotgun) P.Manning pass short left to W.Welker pushed ob at DEN 34 for 10 yards (C.Graham)."]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
                                                   0
0  (12:25) (No Huddle Shotgun) P.Manning pass sho...
```

This will "extract" what's it the group (inside the parenthesis):

```
In [13]: df[0].str.extract("for (\d+)")
Out[13]:
0    10
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [14]: df[0].str.extract("for (\d+) yards")
Out[14]:
0    10
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

*You'll need to convert to int, e.g. using `astype(int)`.*

Comment: Woohoo! Works. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ok. So, I'm getting: AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'extract'. (Sorry, I'm a newb.)

Comment: @mlaugh4 which version of pandas are you using (this is new in 0.13) recommend updating to the latest version (0.13.1) :)

Comment: @mlaugh4 check with  `pd.version.version`

Answer (score -1):

This will grab the number 10 and put it in a variable called yards.

> x = "(12:25) (No Huddle Shotgun) P.Manning pass short left to W.Welker pushed ob at DEN 34 for 10 yards (C.Graham)."
>
> yards = (x.split("for ")[-1]).split(" yards")[0]